# Multiple sticky elements in Elementor

Tags: css, wordpress, element, sticky, elementor

I'm creating a Terms & Conditions page with Elementor. I have two columns with on the left side a menu with all paragraphs of the Terms & Conditions and on the right side the text. All paragraphs (including the titles) are separate widgets.

How can I manage if you click on a paragraph in the menu that you scroll to the desired section in the text? I tried to use the standard menu anchor with margin offset at the bottom (because of the header), but then I'll get al lot of spacing on the whole page between the paragraphs.

[Link](https://www.dierenwinkeldeals.nl/av) to the page.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: show your code.

Comment: I don't have any code, because it's only in Elementor.